# reuse string in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I have a global variable

```
RT="\e[m"
TITLE="${FG}%s${RT}"
```

and have two functions

```
function one
{
   local FG="\e[33m"
   printf "$TITLE" "One"
}

function two
{
   local FG="\e[32m"
   printf "$TITLE" "Two"
}
```

but the color dont change, how to reuse the `$TITLE` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, bash doesn't have the equivalent of pointers. The variable `$TITLE` is assigned with the expansion of the rhs of the assignment character, so `$TITLE` has the value `%s\e[m` since `$FG` is not defined at expansion time, and hence expands to the empty string. As a work-around you could instead do:

```
rt=$'\e[m'
title="%s%s$rt"

one() {
    local fg=$'\e[33m'
    printf "$title" "$fg" "One"
}

two() {
    local fg=$'\e[32m'
    printf "$title" "$fg" "Two"
}
```

And using `eval` is not really a good option, as `eval` is evil!

I've also modified a few things from your script:

- Used lower case variable names (as using upper case variable names is considered bad practice in bash),
- Use `$'...'` to have the correct colors (instead of the strings `"\e[m"`, ...),
- Used the proper way to define functions in bash (without the keyword `function`).

**Edit.** From your comment, I see you're really troubled with having to type `"$fg"` each time. So here's another possibility: instead of defining a variable `$title`, define a function `title` that echos the formating string and use it like so:

```
rt=$'\e[m'

title() {
   echo "$fg%s$rt"
}

one() {
    local fg=$'\e[33m'
    printf "$(title)" "One"
}

two() {
    local fg=$'\e[32m'
    printf "$(title)" "Two"
}
```

Each time you call the function title, it echoes the formating string you need, hence `$(title)` will expand to that formating string. Each time you call the function `title`, the string `"$fg%s$rt"` is expanded, with whatever values the variables `$fg` and `$rt` have at this expansion time.

Comment: your solution works fine, but is necesary the extra parameter $FG for each `printf` command. how aboid this?

Answer (score 1):

TITLE is expanded to include `${FG}` where you type it, not when you use it.  one solution is to:

```
TITLE='${FG}%s${RT}'
```

then

```
eval printf "$TITLE" "One"
```